# Imperavi Redactor + RubyOnRails + Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I need to integrate [Imperavi Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) with [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). But instead of  JavaScript, would like my RubyOnRails application do the upload process, I already use [fog](http://fog.io/), [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) and [imperavi-rails](https://github.com/tanraya/imperavi-rails).

Can you help me?

Comment: did you find a solution to this without relying on the redactor-rails gem?

Answer (score 0):

You can fork [redactor-rails](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) gem and replace the assets with redactor version you bought. It works like a charm.